# Informatica mdm activeVOS not launching

Tags: logging, server, console, informatica, mdm

I am installing active vos. The tomcat server is starting but the active vos console not showing. I am totally new to active vos . Please guide me on what i should check. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, I recommend new users to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on asking questions that are well-suited for the site and best enable the community to provide helpful feedback. In this case, this question is a little bit too vague, it asks very generally for what would constitute a tutorial instead of asking a specific question.